# VB.Net Filling DataGridview with dataset1 table rows

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

Noob here, have imported SQL database as datasource into forms app but when I click preview no rows are shown.

```vb
Public Class Form1
   Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the "DataSet1.Ac_Billbook" table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    'Me.Ac_BillbookTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DataSet1.Ac_Billbook)
    For Each table In DataSet1.Tables
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(table.ToString)
    Next
  End Sub

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
      DataGridView1.DataSource = DataSet1.Tables(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
     'DataGridView1.DataBind()
  End Sub
End Class
```

[image: Output]

The idea is that I would be able to preview table fields by looking at a table and quickly seeing it.

Comment: Try `DataSet1.Tables(ComboBox1.SelectedItem).DefaultView`

Comment: The GridView is now completely blank

Answer (score 0):

You can break down the line where you assigning the table as datasource, so that you can use a breakpoint and use a "dataset visualizer" (small icon with magnifying glass will show it) feature of the VS to check the table content.

[image]
[image]

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt as New DataTable
    dt = DataSet1.Tables(ComboBox1.SelectedItem).DefaultView
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Put a Breakpoint on the line with "DataGridView1.DataSource = dt" and have a look, whether the datatable has the desired rows.
If no data is there, also test with first table:

```
dt = DataSet1.Tables(0).DefaultView
```

If there are still no data, then you get nothing from your DB table(s).

Comment: getting an error on this line: 

`dt = DataSet1.Tables(ComboBox1.SelectedItem).DefaultView)`
 
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataView' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'.

Comment: Hmm, strip away ".DefaultView" then. I see I use .DefaultView with DataSource only. It should work.

Comment: Ok seems to be showing column headings now as per my original post - no rows -  do I need to specify a datamember?

Comment: What do you see in DataSet Visualizer as per instructions and picture above? Is it empty too?

Comment: I suspect, that your table name passed to Tables() doesnn't match or is broken. SelectedItem can give you an array row as a result, by the way (ad it wouldn't work). I would definitely use a Combobox1.ValueMember <string>, set it to table name and then use DataSet1.Tables(ComboBox1.**SelectedValue**). But if you can enumerate your tables, I would definitely use their nubmber indexes (0 to N) as ValueMember values. I'd consider it safer method, if you can keep order in the assignment.